# Diffs at /revisions differ from the diffs at /suggested-edits/

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, revisions-list, diff

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/238/revisions (private beta; please don't make a mess) looks like this:

[image]

The corresponding suggested edit (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/194) looks like this:

[image]

The tags are diffed correctly at the suggested edit page (`-belief`), but not at the revision history page (`-belief -death +death`). I assume the revision history page is the one that's borked; and in any case, it's strange that they don't behave identically.

Comment: Probably another edit in between now makes the diff look different. A different base to compare the changes against.

Comment: As for the tag: the sort order has changed for those tags; `gods` has become more popular than `death` (more posts use it).